# Usuarios conectados (logged)

Tags: linux, bash

Con el comando `who` puede ver los usuarios que han hecho sessión (loggin) en el equipo, pero si una vez estoy dentro accedo a otro usuario via `su -` o sudo `su -`, me gustaría poder mostrarlo también.
Como se puede ver, el usuario `user1` está conectado:

```
*[root@node02 ~]# ps -ef | grep user1
root     28813 28703  0 08:58 pts/10   00:00:00 sudo su - user1
root     28814 28813  0 08:58 pts/10   00:00:00 su - user1
user1    28815 28814  0 08:58 pts/10   00:00:00 -bash
root     28897 28875  0 08:59 pts/11   00:00:00 su - user1
user1    28898 28897  0 08:59 pts/11   00:00:00 -bash
root     29513 28567  0 09:10 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color=auto user1*
```

y si lanzo `who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq` solo me aparece un usuario:

```
[root@node02 ~]# who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq
root
```

Como puedo extraer los usuarios conectados en un equipo?
Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede, te detallo porqué. Aun que la respuesta a tu última pregunta tu mismo ya la has respondido, con el comando `who`.

- Por una parte hay los usuarios logeados en el sistema. Los ves con el comando `who` como bien sabes.
- Por otra parte hay la ejecución de un comando especifico  para ejecutar un programa substituyendo el UID y GID por el indicado. Este es el `su <usuario> [<comando>]`

Cuando haces `su usuario1` sin mas argumentos, estas abriendo una consola interactiva a nombre de `usuario1`. **No te estas logueando** al sistema como usuario `usuario1`. De esa forma, solo lo sabrás con `ps`, como ya has indicado, que te lista los procesos y usuarios en ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios temas en tu pregunta. Por un lado, si quieres saber "a nombre de quién" (gracias a los [*SUID*, o *SGID*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)) están siendo lanzados tal o cual programa, tan sólo modifica tu primer *oneliner*:

```
$ ps -eo user= | awk '!_[$0]++'
root
cuau-user
usuario1
usuario2
```

Aquí, con el segmento de `awk`, tan sólo desduplicamos los usuarios.

Por otro lado, si quieres saber qué usuario está registrado en tu servidor como un nuevo ingreso, puedes utilizar cualquiera de los siguientes comandos:

```
$ finger
$ pinky
$ who
$ w
$ last
```

Por ejemplo, con `last`:

```
$ last
usuario1 pts/9                         Mon Mar 15 13:37 - 13:38  (00:01)
cuau-user pts/5        127.0.0.1        Tue Feb  2 03:15    gone - no logout
cuau-user pts/7        127.0.0.1        Sat Jan 23 21:49    gone - no logout

wtmp begins Sat Jan 23 21:49:54 2021
```

Que, como te comentaban en la respuesta aceptada, los usuarios que listes con `ps`no están relacionados los que están loggeados.

Comment: Gracias!. En este ultimo punto que comentas, Según la fecha de conexión que aparece, puedo calcular los minutos que hay hasta la fecha actual?